# Why was a question directly pertinent to Wordpress migrated off the site?

Tags: discussion, support

This issue is directly pertinent to Wordpress as it has to do with TwentyTwelve and will affect anyone using TwentyTwelve either now or on WP 3.5.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282955/super-long-scroll-past-end-of-page-on-android

It shouldn't have been migrated.

Comment: If you have a concern / question about migration, then meta is the place to raise it, not the main site.

Comment: Agreed with @anu. And it was correctly migrated - read the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) - it was nothing more than a CSS/HTML question, it just happened to be a WP theme.

Answer (score 7):

That question requires knowledge in **CSS**, not in WordPress.

I have migrated it to help you getting better answers.